# tree view svg line kendo

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, kendo-ui

please help me to use jquery ui and kendo to draw line between two tables of tree view

i want to connect the variaables in both tables using svg line

please help me to use jquery ui and kendo to draw line between two tables of tree view

i want to connect the variaables in both tables using svg line

please help me to use jquery ui and kendo to draw line between two tables of tree view

i want to connect the variaables in both tables using svg line

```
       Name: "Furniture",
        expanded: true,
        items: [{


    Name: "Tables & Chairs",
            Id: 1
        }, {
            Name: "Sofas",
            Id: 99
        }, {
            Name: "Occasional Furniture",
            Id: 3
        }]
    }, {
        Name: "Decor",
        items: [{
            Name: "Bed Linen",
            Id: 4
        }, {
            Name: "Curtains & Blinds",
            Id: 5
        }, {
            Name: "Carpets",
            Id: 6
        }]
    }, {
        Name: "Storage",
        Id: 7
    }],

dataTextField: "Name",
    dataValueField: "Id"
}).data('kendoTreeView');






    dataSource: [{
        Name: "Furniture",
        expanded: true,
        items: [{

      Name: "Tables & Chairs",
            Id: 1
        }, {
            Name: "Sofas",
            Id: 99
        }, {
            Name: "Occasional Furniture",
            Id: 3
        }]
    }, {
        Name: "Decor",
        items: [{
            Name: "Bed Linen",
            Id: 4
        }, {
            Name: "Curtains & Blinds",
            Id: 5
        }, {
            Name: "Carpets",
            Id: 6
        }]
    }, {
        Name: "Storage",
        Id: 7
```

Comment: link for above http://jsbin.com/aliniz/499/edit

Comment: i thank for anwser in advance